# How to get the Partitioner in Apache Flink?

Tags: scala, partitioning, apache-flink

we are trying to create an extension for Apache Flink, which uses custom partitioning. For some operators we want to check/retrieve the used partitioner. Unfortunately, I could not find any possibility to do this on a given DataSet. Have I missed something or is there another workaround for this?

I would start with something like this:

```scala
class MyPartitioner[..](..) extends Partitioner[..] {..}
[..]
val myP = new MyPartitioner(...)
val ds = in.partitionCustom(myP, 0)
```

Now from another class I would like to access the partitioner (if defined). In Spark I would do it the following way:

```scala
val myP = ds.partitioner.get.asInstanceOf[MyPartitioner]
```

However, for Flink I could not find a possibility for this.

---

**Edit1:**

It seems to be possible with the [suggestion of Fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40228701/7063374). However, there are two limitations:

(1) When using Scala you have to retrieve the underlying Java DataSet first to cast it to a `PartitionOperator`

(2) The partitioning must be the last operation. So one can not use other operations between setting and getting the partitioner. E.g. the following is not possible:

```scala
val in: DataSet[(String, Int)] = ???

val myP = new MyPartitioner()
val ds = in.partitionCustom(myP, 0)
val ds2 = ds.map(x => x)

val myP2 = ds2.asInstanceOf[PartitionOperator].getCustomPartitioner
```

Thank you and best regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the returned `DataSet` into a `PartitionOperator` and call `PartitionOperator.getCustomPartitioner()`:

```
val in: DataSet[(String, Int)] = ???

val myP = new MyPartitioner()
val ds = in.partitionCustom(myP, 0)

val myP2 = ds.asInstanceOf[PartitionOperator].getCustomPartitioner
```

Note that

1. `getCustomPartitioner()` is an internal method (i.e., not part of the public API) and might change in future versions of Flink.
2. `PartitionOperator` is also used for other partitioning types, such as `DataSet.partitionByHash()`. In these cases `getCustomPartitioner()` might return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fabian. This was also something that I was thinking of. I have just tried it. However, when using some other operators in between (such as `map`) this is not possible anymore, although the partitioning should be the same. On top of that, the cast is only possible when I retrieve the Java DataSet before.
I will update the question soon.

Comment: The partitioner is not passed on to the next operator. I think the only way to retrieve it for a chain such as `val out: DataSet = in.partitionCustom(...).map(...)` is to traverse the operators back to the `PartitionOperator` by casting `DataSet` to a `SingleInputOperator` and calling `getInput()`.

Comment: Okay, this would mean if I do not know where or whether an `PartitionOperator` is set it would be necessary to traverse potentially the complete operator tree/chain with a lot of type checks and casts. Have you thought of eventually adding a future feature for this intention?